# Select the required records from Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I did a cogroup of a,b in c and the schema and output of C is below .
c = cogroup a by $1,b by $1;`
 * Schema is {group: bytearray,a:{()},b:{()}}

```
         c = {(1,2,3,4)} {(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12),(13,14,15,16)}

         Now, How do I generate B as below in Pig?
         1,2,3,4  Assume this is a Policy record
         5,6,7,8  Assume this is a Role1 record for the policy
         9,10,11,12  Assume this is a Role2 record for the policy
         13,14,15,16 Assume this is a Role3 record for the policy
         ##Appreciate the help and thankful for it.##
```

Comment: What is exactly your goal?

Comment: I want to generate each tuple from C one by one. I could not edit the content here.